# Filter out pandas pivot table rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pivot table like so:

```
datadict={('Imps', '10day avg'): {'Kept': 8893221.8000000007,
  'RTB': 2038806.0909090908,
  'Resold': 2924189.3500000001},
 ('Imps', '30day avg'): {'Kept': 4597369.7000000002,
  'RTB': 1167544.7272727273,
  'Resold': 1399503.1000000001},
 ('Imps', '3day avg'): {'Kept': 8581754.9000000004,
  'RTB': 1826690.0909090908,
  'Resold': 3631253.5499999998},
 ('Revenue', '10day avg'): {'Kept': 1116.52816874,
  'RTB': 664.17077545454549,
  'Resold': 390.27436701499994},
 ('Revenue', '30day avg'): {'Kept': 576.10828001333334,
  'RTB': 352.93580718181818,
  'Resold': 199.26966106333327},
 ('Revenue', '3day avg'): {'Kept': 791.95915710000008,
  'RTB': 490.23978787878792,
  'Resold': 384.58885283333336}}

df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(datadict)
df.columns = pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns)
```

I would like to filter it to only show rows where the max revenue across all periods for each 'Imp Type' (ie RTB, Kept, Resold) is above a certain threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Imps Type' not 'Imp Type' right? If the cut off is 3000000:

```
In [9]:

print df[(df['Imps']>3000000).any(axis=1)]
              Imps                             Revenue                        
         10day avg  30day avg    3day avg    10day avg   30day avg    3day avg
Kept    8893221.80  4597369.7  8581754.90  1116.528169  576.108280  791.959157
Resold  2924189.35  1399503.1  3631253.55   390.274367  199.269661  384.588853

[2 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: almost, but not quite what I'm looking for. This filters the row out if any of the values are under the threshold. My goal was to filter out rows where the max value was below the threshold.

Comment: Meaning keeping the rows where at least one of the value are above the threshold, or drop the rows where all the values are below the threshold? See edit.